# Calculating gradients in optical flow optimization (example: for incremental Horn and Schunck method)

Tags: optimization, gradient, opticalflow

I am having a problem in understanding the way how gradients are calculated for the incremental Horn and Schunck method (but actually, not only for that method, but more generally in iterative optimization methods for optical flow/deformable image registration). I use the Horn and Schunck example here, because there I can refer a paper that shows what is unclear to me.

I was reading the following paper http://campar.in.tum.de/pub/zikic2010revisiting/zikic2010revisiting.pdf that states that incremental Horn and Schunck method is actually the same as using Gauss-Newton optimization scheme on the original problem. In incremental Horn and Schunck, the solution of one Horn and Schunck iteration is used as the initial estimate for the following one: the displacement field is used to warp the source image, then the next Horn and Schunck iteration is used to calculate an incremental step. Afterwards, the initial estimate and the step are added and used as initialization for the next iteration. So far, so good, one can do this, even if I wouldn't say it is intuitive that this procedure of splitting things up and putting them back together should be correct.

Now the paper states that this (at first sight heuristic) approach can be derived as a Gauss-Newton optimization, which means it should have a more mathematical foundation. Now I find a motif that I came across more than once but cannot reason about:

In the term

IT(x)-IS(x+U(x))

, IT is the target image and IS is the source image, U(x) is the deformation field that is optimized.

When linearizing this energy term around a certain current deformation field value U(x) (in the paper it is equation 19, I changed it slightly), we get for a step h(x)

linearized(h(x))≡IT(x)−IS(x+U(x))−grad(IS(x+U(x)))*h(x)

Now the question is: WHAT is grad(IS(x+U(x)))? The authors argue that this would then be the same gradient as in the incremental Horn and Schunck method, but: I would say, the gradient needs to be taken wrt U(x). That means I would take the numerical gradient of IS at position x+U(x). However, I have seen now often that instead, the image is warped according to U(x), and then the numerical gradient of the warped image is taken at position x. This seems also to be what in incremental Horn and Schunck is done, however, it doesn't seem correct to me.

Is it an approximation that nobody talks about? Do I miss something? Or were all implementations that I saw using numerical gradients of warped images when iteratively optimizing for optical flow just doing the wrong thing?

Many thanks to anybody who could help me to get a bit enlightened.